# How does the shell filename expansion delimit items within a ( * ) list?

Tags: bash, shell

I don't understand shell expansion fully yet (hopefully, one day soon I will)...
I saw this comment to a [superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/36710/linux-shell-is-shell-a-must), but I think I'm still parked at the kerb...

> Using Linux without the shell is like driving a Ferrari at 50 km/h through city traffic. All fun will just go away ...

I don't understand the following example.. What heirarchy, or whatever, is causing the 2nd example "array item count:" to be different to the 1st example?

What happened to the shell introduced "space"?. or is it the `echo` which is introducing the space, and the shell is (perhaps) using \0?

```
#!/bin/bash
# Make a couple of files whose names contain a space.
junkd=$HOME/junkd
mkdir $junkd # || exit 1
cd $junkd
touch f\ {1..2}
#
echo -n * |xxd         # This shows a space between the two names.
names=$(echo -n * )
echo -n "$names" |xxd  # This shows a space between the two names.
#
# So far, it seems that the shell is inserting a space between each filename.
#
array=( $names )
echo "array item count: ${#array[@]}" 
# 4 items... This shows that a space is the delimiter char ....
#
array=( * )
echo "array item count: ${#array[@]}" 
# 2 items... What happened to the shell introduced space?
#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From **man bash**

> **EXPANSION**
>          Expansion is performed on the command line after it has been split
>   into words.  There are seven kinds
>          of  expansion  performed: brace expansion, tilde expansion, parameter
>   and variable expansion, command
>          substitution, arithmetic expansion, word splitting, and
>   pathname expansion.
>   The order of expansions is: brace
>   expansion, tilde  expansion, 
>   parameter,  variable  and  arithmetic
>          expansion  and  command  substitution (done in a left-to-right
>   fashion), word splitting, and pathname
>          expansion.

```
array=( $names )
```

The reason this gives you 4 entries is because an unquoted `$names` parameter is further subject to *word splitting* based on the internal field separator `IFS` which is by default `<space><tab><newline>`.  If you were to quote `"$names"` to inhibit word splitting, then you'll only get one array element with value `f 1 f 2`, again not what you want.

```
array=( * )
```

The above on the other hand is only subject to *pathname expansion* which happens to be the last expansion performed.  The results are *not* subject to word splitting thus you get the desired 2 elements.

If you want to make `array=( $names )` work then you'll need to somehow separate the file names by a non-space character which also is not contained in the file names.  You'll then need to set IFS to this character.

```
$ names=$(echo f* | sed "s/ /#/2")
$ echo $names
f 1#f 2
$ IFS='#' array=( $names )
$ echo ${#array[@]}
2
$ echo ${array[0]}
f 1
```

A more elegant way to do this would be to use the NUL byte `\0` as the filename delimiter as that is guaranteed to never be apart of a filename.  To accomplish this we will need to use the `find` command with its `-print0` flag as well as the `read` builtin delimited on NUL. We well also need to clear IFS so no word splitting on spaces is performed.

```
#!/bin/bash

unset array

while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' name; do
  array+=( "$name" )
done < <(find . -type f -name "f*" -print0 )
```

#### Update

> Expansion is performed on the command
>   line after it has been split into
>   words.

I can see how one would be confused by the quote above only to have it further state that *word splitting* is the 2nd to last expansion to occur.

A better way to word that quote in my opinion would be:

> Expansion is performed on the command
>   line after it has been split into
>   **arguments**.

The splitting of arguments on the shell is *always* done by white space, and it's those arguments which are further subject to expansion. If you want to have white space in your argument you must either use *Quoting* or *Escaping*. `IFS` does not augment argument splitting, only word splitting.

Consider this example:

```
$ touch f{1,2}; IFS="#"; rm f1#f2
rm: cannot remove `f1#f2': No such file or directory
```

Notice how setting `IFS` to `#` did not alter the fact that the shell still only saw one argument `f1#f2`; which by the way is then further subject to the various expansions.

I would highly recommend your aquatint yourself with the [BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) if you haven't already.  In particular, I would strongly suggest you read the following two supplemental entries:

1. [Arguments](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments)
2. [Word Splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting)

Comment: I'm slowly getting there. I've started reading the entire `man bash` (10% so far :). Now, about this issue in particular. I'm starting to get a feel for it, but unless my compehension is way off, the man page excerpt you quoted, says, `"Expansion is performed on the command line after it has been split into words..."` and then goes on to say that one of the "expansions" is `word splitting`. That looks like a contradiction.. so it brings up the "mechanism" issue again..  I've just noticed Gilles has posted and mentions something about "shell words".. (but I must go now... back later)

Comment: @fred.bear please see my updated answer, this should put to rest any doubt you may have had regarding the "mechanics" of the shell.

Comment: I'm sure the answer is probably glaringly obvious in both yours and Gilles' answer, but untill I can actually see it, I can't assess the 'best' answer.. They are both good answers and have got me on the right track ... I'm about to go through your updated answer now... Perhaps I'm missing the point because I've been thinking that the only thing that "word splitting" did was to remove duplicate spaces between any and all "words", but I'm starting to think that filename expansion creates a very non-human word (ie. a word which includes spaces), otherwise how does the array assignment work?

Comment: Introducing the word "argument", won the argument. It tallies with my evolving line of thought, so I probably do understand it now...(I just need to put it into practice)... It did however take two of you to get through my thick scull on this one, and I thank you both for the information in both answers.. I've learnt different things from both.

Answer (score 5):

A shell command (more precisely, a “simple command”) consists of a list of words. Each word can be an arbitrary string (a shell word can contain spaces and punctuation characters).

When you run `echo -n *`, the shell performs pathname expansion (also called filename generation or globbing) on `*`, and replaces it by the list of matching file names. So after expansion, this command consists of four words: `echo`, `-n`, `f 1` and `f 2`. The command `echo` is run with two arguments, and it prints its arguments with a space in between (and no terminating newline because of the `-n` option). So the output is `f 1 f 2`. *Exercise: create another file whose name consists of two consecutive spaces, run `echo -n *`, and make sure you understand the output.*

When you run `names=$(echo -n * )`, the output from the command is stored in the `names` variable. Here, that line is equivalent to `names='f 1 f 2'`.

Now we get to `array=( $names )`. That's an array assignment, but it doesn't affect the expansion in this case. Since `$names` is an unquoted variable expansion, it's subject to word splitting followed by pathname expansion. Word splitting means that the value of the variable (which is a string) is split into pieces at each whitespace sequence (for the precise rules, search `IFS` in your shell's documentation). You can end up with zero, one or more words; here the string is split into 4 words: `f`, `1`, `f` and `2`. So the array contains four elements (each a one-character word). *Exercise: with that extra file with two consecutive spaces in its name, what is now the exact contents of the array?*

Next, you tried `array=( * )`. Here, there's a single word in the array, subject to the usual expansions, the last of which is pathname expansion. Since there are two matching files, the array contains two words, the names of each file: `f 1` and `f 2`.

In terms of shell programming practice, what advice can we draw from this analysis? Well, first, there's the usual shell programming principle: always put double quotes around variable expansions, unless you have a good reason not to. Then, don't store a list in a string variable. If you want to store a list of file names, put it directly in an array:

```
files=(*)
ls -l "${files[@]}"
```

*Further exercise: create a file whose name is a single asterisk (`touch '*'`) and run these commands again. Do you understand the output?*

Aside: zsh does not perform word splitting or pathname expansion on variable expansions. This makes it quite a bit saner to program in.

Comment: Was there something in my answer that you did not find sufficient or was this a point grab? Just curious

Comment: @SiegeX: Apart from the useless diversion with `#` as a separator (which won't work if a file name contains `#`), your answer is correct. But it's not very didactic. In particular, you don't explain that a command is not a string but a list of strings, which is often confusing to shell beginners.

Comment: We'll have to agree to disagree on the `#` example because I explicitly used it to be didactic; It's much easier to visualize `#` than the NUL byte. I also made special note that this char must not be apart of the filename and then proceeded to give the more proper NUL byte solution.  From my perspective, your answer was 90% the same and the other 10% would have been more appropriate as a comment. But, you can't get to 21K for making only comments so C'est la vie.

Comment: @SiegeX: If you think my answer is 90% the same as yours, you need to work on your pedagogy. We are explaining the same facts very differently.

Comment: The pedantry of your diction is indubitability noted.

Comment: LOL :) .... My current status (still working on it): It seems that there is a 6 levels hierarchy of "shell expansion" (from `brace expansion` thru to `pathname expansion`). I can therefore understand that the example of `files=(*)` does not go through `word splitting`. However, it seems to me that the `pathname expansion` somehow internally(?) delimits the filenames by some other means than a space, because to my understanding the array asignment () would produce 4 items.. so is there some *special* interaction happening with these file-expansion words? This may be at the core of my puzzle.

Comment: It seems that there are two types of *words* here.. 1) a word which is the result of the `word splitting` (IFS), and 2) another type of *word* which is the result of `pathname expansion` which is independant of the IFS (unless echo'd or suchlike) ... The second type is treated as a unit, as though it was quoted..  It seems like this is what is happening  internally...

Comment: @Gilles:  Thanks for an excellent answer (again :)...  This one was of particular note to me: *"If you want to store a list of file names, put it directly in an array"* ...  I believe I know how (and when) to do that now, thanks to the two good answers put forward.

Comment: @fred.bear: There's only one type of word, and it can contain any character, including whitespace. Pathname expansion creates a list of words: each filename gets its own word. Word splitting happens before pathname expansion, so in `file=(*)`, `*` undergoes word splitting (yielding the one-word list `*`), then the single resulting word undergoes pathname expansion (yielding the list of file names).

Comment: @Gilles: You say "...only one type of word". Okay, I'm running with that. This suggests that word-splitting means: Splitting **OF** a Word into sub Words based on IFS.. I had thought that word-splitting meant splitting **AT** word boundries, and that the words involved were those demarked by the IFS, and the nett result was that adjacent IFS chars were reduced to a single (1st)-IFS-char... BUT I was wrong :).. As you've mentioned, it seems that in shell-expansion jargon, a **Word** is an arbitrary string which is, as per precedence rules, subject to word-splitting... I think I've got it :)

Comment: @fred.bear: Yes. For example, try splitting the same word twice, but changing the value of `IFS` in between: you'll get different splits. (`foo="one two  three,four,,five"; echo $foo; IFS=,; echo $foo`)